# Clearing messages from the client cache in a ServiceBusQueue with prefetch_count > 0 and mode = receiveanddelete

Tags: python, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to improve the performance of my Python ingestion from a ServiceBusQueue. At first I tried to increase the `max_wait_time` and the `max_message_count`, but I usually only get between 20-40% of the `max_message_count` per call of `receive_messages(max_message_count)`. The call returns in ~1.2 seconds even though the `max_wait_time` is 30 seconds (I suppose the function prefers returning early over filling the `max_message_count` completely).

So I wanted to decrease the time it takes to receive messages by configuring the `prefetch_count = 10000` so the client caches messages and whenever I call `receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)` next, it can pull messages from the cache instead of making a separate call to the Queue each time.

At the same time my ingestion mode is `receive and delete`, meaning any message retrieved from the queue is instantly deleted.

My Problem: I believe if my client application terminates before processing all the prefetched messages, **the remaining messages in the prefetch buffer will be lost** (since they are already removed from the Queue) - which is undesirable.

- How can I "clear out" (and process) all prefetched messages without retrieving a new batch from the Queue once I decide to stop my ingestion application?
- Or should I just never set the `prefetch_count` > 0 with `receiveanddelete` mode?

My configuration of the ServiceBusReceiver:

```
prefetch_count = 10000  # on get_queue_receiver()
max_wait_time = 30  # on get_queue_receiver()
receive_mode = receiveanddelete   # on get_queue_receiver()
max_messages_count = 3000  # on receive_messages()
```

Pseudo example:

```
service_bus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(current_connection_string)
queue_receiver = service_bus_client.get_queue_receiver(
        current_queue_name,
        max_wait_time=30,
        receive_mode='receiveanddelete',
        prefetch_count=10000,
    )
# Get messages (including prefetch for the next call of 'receive_messages')
#    and immediately remove all of it from the queue.
msgs_1 = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)

# This call might not even need to contact the Queue, but can 
#   just get pre-fetched messages from the cache:
msgs_2 = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)

# If I stop now - how do I make sure that my client-side cache 
#   (due to prefetch_count > 0 ) is actually empty?
```

In theory, in my example I prefetched 10.000 messages during my first call of `receive_messages()`, but only called `receive_messages()` once again afterwards: 10.000 - 3.000 = 7.000

How do I make sure that I do not loose ~7.000 prefetched messages which reside in my client cache? Maybe even more as I do not always get 3000 messages back on each call of 'receive_messages'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a separate method to prefetch all the messaged and process them from the prefetch buffer  in a loop and then stop processing after the buffer returns empty to stop the ingestion.

I have referred the code from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues?tabs=connection-string) to send and receive messages in Service bus.

**My Sbreceiver.py code:-**

```py
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient

# Create an instance of the ServiceBusClient
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="Endpoint=sb://siliconservicebus45.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxW6BY=", logging_enable=False)

# Create a receiver instance with prefetch
queue_receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name="testqueue", prefetch_count=10000, max_wait_time=30)

def process_messages():
    received_messages = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)
    
    for message in received_messages:
        # Process the message here
        process_messages(message)
        
        # Mark the message as complete so that it's deleted from the queue
        queue_receiver.complete_message(message)

# Call the process_messages function to start ingesting and processing messages
process_messages()

# Close the receiver and the client when you're done
queue_receiver.close()
servicebus_client.close()
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Updated:-**

> By executing the queue_receiver.receive_messages() function with a  max_message_count parameter set to the number of prefetched messages, you can delete the prefetched messages. After doing so, the cache will be cleared of all the prefetched messages. These messages can then be handled before your ingestion application is terminated. When utilising the receiveanddelete mode, the prefetch_count should never be set to a value higher than zero if you don't want to lose any prefetched messages.

Refer this [**Document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-prefetch.md) for more information.

An alternative code is to manually process and acknowledge each message so that you do not lose any prefetched messages.

sample code:-

```py
from sbreceiver1 import process_messages


service_bus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="Endpoint=sb://siliconservicebus45.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxm+ASbJ5W6BY=")
queue_receiver = service_bus_client.get_queue_receiver(
    "testqueue",
    max_wait_time=30,
    receive_mode='receiveanddelete',
    prefetch_count=10000,
)

msgs_1 = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)


for msg in msgs_1:
    process_messages(msg)  
    msg.complete() 

msgs_2 = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)


for msg in msgs_2:
    process_messages(msg)  
    msg.complete() 

# Acknowledge any remaining prefetched messages
while True:
    msgs = queue_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=3000)
    if not msgs:
        break

    for msg in msgs:
        process_messages(msg)  # Replace with your message processing logic
        msg.complete()  # Acknowledge the message

# Close the receiver and the client when you're done
queue_receiver.close()
servicebus_client.close()
```

Comment: 1) In your code, you use the default `peeklock` mode (which is why you call `complete_message(message)` to remove them from the Queue). In my example (`receiveanddelete`), they are removed as soon as I call `receive_messages`.
2) Furthermore, your variable `received_messages(...)` only contains the messages which were retrieved, *not the ones which were cached/prefetched* ! Meaning, your example doesn't actually empty the cache of prefetched messages anywere.

Comment: I added a pseudo example to my question

Comment: @Cribber Check my Updated answer? and check if you get any insights

Comment: The quote is spot-on, basically tells me not to use `prefetch > 0` in combination with the `receiveanddelete` mode! One last question - where did you get the quote from? I can't find it in the linked document

Comment: By default, I put that quote in block just because it was important. "PrefetchCount is set to 0, which means that no additional messages are fetched from the service" from this document and the prefetching paragraph -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#prefetching

Comment: Ah alright, thanks anyway! I guess it really is exclusive... either I use prefetch or I use receiveanddelete.